# How does xchg works with string for assembly x86?

Tags: assembly, x86

I want to exchange what's in `str_1` to `str_2` and from `str_2` to `str_1` using `xchg` instruction?

```
.STACK  4096            ; reserve 4096-byte stack
.DATA 

str_1       BYTE "elimination",  0
str_2       BYTE "description", 0 

.CODE  

_start:

;how would you use it here ? 
; lets say we use ESI, edi 

    lea esi, str_1
    lea edi, str_2

;I want to know how I can use xchg?

    INVOKE ExitProcess, 0
PUBLIC _start                   ; make entry point public

END                             ; end of source code
```

Comment: You should probably clarify what you *intend* your code to do.

Comment: I want to exchange whats in str_1 to str_2 and from str_2 to str_1 using xchg instruction?

Comment: That's not going to happen, the longer one doesn't fit in the shorter one so `str_2` will point somewhere in the middle of the first string if you just swapped the contents like that (and you'd have no pointer to the second string).

Comment: As @harold pointed out, you can't swap the *contents* of the two strings. You *can*, however, swap the *pointers*. `xchgl %edi, %esi` should do it. Of course, in this example, you could simply have loaded the addresses to the other register in the first place...

Comment: Lets say str_1 "elimination" and str_2 "description" the string length is 11 for both words. How would you do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a C-function to test this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

void swapfun(char *restrict fp, char *restrict sp)
{
  while (*fp)
    {
      char temp = *fp;
      *fp++ = *sp;
      *sp++ = temp;
    }
  return;
}
```

`gcc 4.8 -O3` suggests the following (x86-64, but it's easily adaptable):

```
swapfun:
    jmp .L10
.L7:
    movzbl  (%rsi), %edx
    addq    $1, %rdi
    addq    $1, %rsi
    movb    %dl, -1(%rdi)
    movb    %al, -1(%rsi)
.L10:
    movzbl  (%rdi), %eax
    testb   %al, %al
    jne .L7
    rep ret
```

`-Os` produces the following, shorter code:

```
swapfun:
    xorl    %eax, %eax
.L2:
    movb    (%rdi,%rax), %dl
    testb   %dl, %dl
    je  .L5
    movb    (%rsi,%rax), %cl
    movb    %dl, (%rsi,%rax)
    movb    %cl, (%rdi,%rax)
    incq    %rax
    jmp .L2
.L5:
    ret
```

I can easily believe the `-O3` code is faster, as it avoids partial register updates via `movzx`, allowing register renaming for out-of-order execution. Neither of the versions use `xchg`, partly because there's no zero-extending version like with `mov`. But you could write something like:

```
swapfun:
    xorl    %eax, %eax
.L2:
    movb    (%rdi,%rax), %dl
    testb   %dl, %dl
    je  .L5
    xchgb   (%rsi,%rax), %dl
    movb    %dl, (%rdi,%rax)
    incq    %rax
    jmp .L2
.L5:
    ret
```

Note that you *cannot* do `xchg (%edi), (%esi)` or the likes, as almost no x86-instruction permits two memory-operands.